# I need to create XML from each CSV pipe separated file in Mule 3.8.4 EE

Tags: csv, mule

For Ex:
If my CSV file consists data as

UserId|Account|Password|Title|FirstName|MiddleName|LastName
123|12345|password|Mr|FN|M|LN
123|12345|password|Mr|FN1|M1|LN1

then I need 2 xml

Comment: Hi, you need to specify clearly what outputs exactly you are expecting for that input.

Comment: Hi @aled there should be 2 xml as <userId>123</userId>
<Account>12345</Account>
<Password>password</Password>
<Title>Mr</Title>
<FirstName>FN</FirstName>
<MiddleName>M</MiddleName>
<LastName>LN</LastName>
and
<userId>123</userId>
<Account>12345</Account>
<Password>password</Password>
<Title>Mr</Title>
<FirstName>FN1</FirstName>
<MiddleName>M1</MiddleName>
<LastName>LN1</LastName>

Answer (score 0):

First convert the CSV to Java, setting the separator to `|`. Then for each record convert it to XML. Remember that a valid XML needs a root element. You example output missed a root. I added one to make it valid.

```
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
      <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/csv" >
        <dw:reader-property name="separator" value="|" />
      </dw:input-payload>
      <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
          %output application/java
          ---
          payload map $
          ]]>     
      </dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <logger message="payload=#[payload]" level="INFO"/>
    <foreach >
      <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
          %output application/xml
          ---
          result: payload
          ]]>     
        </dw:set-payload>
      </dw:transform-message>
      <logger message="XML=#[payload]" level="INFO"/>
      
      <!-- send the XML to somewhere -->
    </foreach>
```

Each iteration of the `foreach` generates one XML. You have to do something with them